# Entity Framework Find the first 7 day gap in date range

Tags: c#, entity-framework, date

I have a list of dates in a DB.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to find the  first day where there is atleast 7 days before the next date.

Is there an aggregate function that could do something like this?

```
return context.SBHolidays.Where((h1, h2) =>DbFunctions.DiffDays(h1, h2) > 6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your `SBHoliday` entity has a `DateTime` property on it.

```
var query = from h1 in context.SBHolidays
            let nextDate = context.SBHolidays                                     
                                  .Where(h2 => h2.Date > h1.Date)
                                  .OrderBy(h2 => h2.Date)
                                  .FirstOrDefault()
            where DbFunctions.DiffDays(h1.Date, nextDate.Date ) > 6
            orderby h1.Date
            select nextDate.Date;

var firstDate = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I gotta test this right now but it makes sense and looks good

Answer (score 0):

The other answer wasn't working due to a wrapper we place on EF however here is another solution which should work

```
var firstHolidayWithGap = context.SBHolidays.OrderBy(h => h.HolidayDate)
    .Select((h, i) => new {h, i}).Distinct()
    .Join(context.SBHolidays.OrderBy(h => h.HolidayDate)
                                          .Select((h, i) => new {h, i}).Distinct(),
          h1 => h1.i,
          h2 => h2.i + 1,
         (h1, h2) => new {h1 = h1.h.HolidayDate, h2 = h2.h.HolidayDate})
   .Where(h => DbFunctions.DiffDays(h.h1, h.h2) > 7)
   .Select(h => h.h1).FirstOrDefault();
```